# Lost my old-Electrum 12-word mnemonic seed order

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I created my wallet some years ago, and wrote my seed phrase on paper, but unfortunately in a wrong order. Now I suddenly found my note and after some check I find it is in the old-Electrum wordlists. But still I couldn’t find the right order of it. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that the 12 words are the correct words but merely in the wrong order, and you know the addresses from the wallet, it is possible to brute force: there are 479,001,600 possible combinations, which isn't too many.

Here is an example of a tool that can help you with this: https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover/blob/master/docs/BIP39_descrambling_seedlists.md
https://github.com/3rdIteration/btcrecover/blob/master/docs/Seedrecover_Quick_Start_Guide.md

Comment: Thank you, I may need to look up for my addresses now.

Comment: @五点共圆 has this been solved?